# Office not Showing Taskpane

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, custom-functions-excel, excel-web-addins

I have created a code which will open taskpane automatically when add-in loaded successfully.
As per the documentation i have passed the resid in the office.addin.showAsTaskpane() , but when i run the project it will always open first default taskpane. I not able to find that where i am doing mistake. Can any one look into that and tell me what is the mistake in the code.
I am uploading code of command.js and xml file.
[1] Code of command.js

```
Office.onReady(() => {
//code for opening taskpan
  Office.addin.showAsTaskpane('Commands.Url').then(function(){
    console.log("successfully loaded add-in")
  })

});

/**
 * Shows a notification when the add-in command is executed.
 * @param event
 */
async function action(event) {
  // Your code goes here
  event.completed();
}

function getGlobal() {
  return typeof self !== "undefined"
    ? self
    : typeof window !== "undefined"
      ? window
      : typeof global !== "undefined"
        ? global
        : undefined;
}

const g = getGlobal();

// the add-in command functions need to be available in global scope
g.action = action;
```

[2] XML of add-in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
  <Id>a1753eec-7c8b-4dbd-ab74-3b30d63d9b15</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Contoso</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Contoso" />
  <Description DefaultValue="Write your own Excel functions in JavaScript." />
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/lock.png" />
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/lock.png" />
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.contoso.com/help" />
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://localhost:3000</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Workbook" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
      <Set Name="SharedRuntime" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html" />
  </DefaultSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="Workbook">
        <Runtimes>
          <Runtime resid="Taskpane.Url" lifetime="long" />
        </Runtimes>
        <AllFormFactors>
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="CustomFunctions">
            <Script>
              <SourceLocation resid="Functions.Script.Url" />
            </Script>
            <Page>
              <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url" />
            </Page>
            <Metadata>
              <SourceLocation resid="Functions.Metadata.Url" />
            </Metadata>
            <Namespace resid="namespace" />
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </AllFormFactors>
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <GetStarted>
            <Title resid="GetStarted.Title" />
            <Description resid="GetStarted.Description" />
            <LearnMoreUrl resid="GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl" />
          </GetStarted>
          <FunctionFile resid="Taskpane.Url" />
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
            <CustomTab id="TabAddIns">
              <Group id="CommandsGroup">
                <Label resid="CommandsGroup.Label" />
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                </Icon>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="TaskpaneButton">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId>
                    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="RA.SearchAndRedact">
                  <Label resid="RA.SearchAndRedact.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                    <Description resid="RA.SearchAndRedact.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <TaskpaneId>ButtonId2</TaskpaneId>
                    <SourceLocation resid="Commands.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
              <Label resid="TabLabel" />
            </CustomTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/lock.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/lock.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/lock.png" />
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="Functions.Script.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/dist/functions.js" />
        <bt:Url id="Functions.Metadata.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/dist/functions.json" />
        <bt:Url id="Functions.Page.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/dist/functions.html" />
        <bt:Url id="GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl" DefaultValue="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=276812" />
        <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html" />
        <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html" />
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="Functions.Namespace" DefaultValue="developer" />
        <bt:String id="GetStarted.Title" DefaultValue="Get started with your sample add-in!" />
        <bt:String id="CommandsGroup.Label" DefaultValue="Get help" />
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Login" />
        <bt:String id="RA.SearchAndRedact.Label" DefaultValue="User Guide" />
        <bt:String id="TabLabel" DefaultValue="Test" />
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="GetStarted.Description" DefaultValue="Your sample add-in loaded succesfully. Go to the HOME tab and click the 'Show Taskpane' button to get started." />
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Show a Taskpane" />
        <bt:String id="RA.SearchAndRedact.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Show a Taskpane" />
        <bt:String id="RA.aboutus.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Show about us" />
        <bt:String id="refreshtab.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Show a Taskpane" />
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Comment: Are you familiar with this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/automatically-open-on-installation

Answer (score 0):

The following section from the manifest file doesn't contain a valid information about the task pane that should be opened:

```
<Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
   <TaskpaneId>ButtonId2</TaskpaneId>
   <SourceLocation resid="Commands.Url" />
</Action>
```

To designate a task pane as the default, add a `TaskpaneId` element as the first child of the `<Action>` element and set its value to `Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument`. The following is an example.

```
<Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
    <TaskpaneId>Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument</TaskpaneId>
    <SourceLocation resid="Contoso.Taskpane.Url" />
</Action>
```

The `SourceLocation` element should point to the task pane page.

Read more about that in the [Automatically open a task pane when an add-in is installed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/automatically-open-on-installation) article.